# Let f : A → B be a function, and let X ⊆ A and Y ⊆ B . Show that $f(f^{−1}(Y)) = Y ∩ f(A)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I already proved $X ⊆ f^{-1}(f(X))$ and $f(f^{-1}(Y)) ⊆ Y$, but has no clear idea about the proof of $f(f^{−1}(Y)) = Y ∩ f(A)$. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you see why $f(f^{-1}(Y))\subseteq f(A)$?  How about the other inclusions?  Also, what is $X$ doing here?

Comment: To be more specific, if you've already proved that $f(f^{-1}(Y))\subseteq Y$, then what remains to be done is to prove that $f(f^{-1}(Y)) \subseteq f(A)$ and that $Y\cap f(A) \subseteq f(f^{-1}(Y))$. The first one should be easy; as for the second one, the proof would start "Suppose that $y\in Y\cap f(A)$; then $y\in Y$ and $y\in f(A)$...", and then would use the definitions of $f(A)$ and $f^{-1}(Y)$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments! I proved this in the way Greg provided. Do I need to delete this question or wait for other people to provide a thorough solution?